# React Native ListView with Realm Results

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm, react-native-listview

I am trying to create a react-native ListView that renders the results returned by Realm. I have been following the instructions I have found regarding react-native's ListView and how to use Realm.

However I always get the same error: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Results]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of 'Text'.`

From what I understand from the Realm documentation and other articles the Results object is supposed to behave like a javascript list and should therefore be accepted into the cloneWithRows method.

If somebody can please tell me what I am doing wrong or how to fix this it would be much appreciated.

P.S. I have tried both react-native's ListView and Realm's ListView and both behave the same way.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Navigator,
    TouchableHighlight,
    TouchableOpacity,
    //ListView,
} from 'react-native';
import { ListView } from 'realm/react-native';

import realm from './myrealm'

class contextview extends Component {
    getState() {
        console.log("getInitialState");
        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        let pictures = [ realm.objects('picture').filtered('new == true') ];
        console.log("pictures: " + pictures);
        return {
            //dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3']),
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(pictures)
        };
    }

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.getState();
        this.bindMethods();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
        />
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause which was in my render method,

Instead of:

```
render() {
  return (
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
    />
  );
}
```

I should have done:

```
render() {
  return (
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.path}</Text>}
    />
  );
}
```

Since the `rowData` was an object ReactNative couldn't render it in a Text element

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this error when calling `cloneWithRows`? If so you might need to instead call `cloneWithRows` on a snapshot of the `Realm.Results` object when using `Realm.ListView`. This is done in the Realm example [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample/components/todo-listview.js#L115). So perhaps try using the `Realm.ListView` and changing your code to:

```
let pictures = [ realm.objects('picture').filtered('new == true').snapshot() ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out and it didn't change anything for me which eventually led me to finding the cause of the error.